# Pasar datos de un Dialog (componente B) a mi ventana principal (componente A) en Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Tengo una tabla en un Dialog (mi componente B) de la cual tengo que seleccionar un código para ser insertado en un input en mi ventana principal (componente A).

Answer (score 0):

Si el Dialog lo abres desde el componente A

Puedes definir que variable pasar cuando el dialog se cierra

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancelar</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="codigo" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

Con [mat-dialog-close]="codigo"

Y suscribirte a ese evento en el componente A y obtener ese valor como resultado.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Dialog cerrado');
      this.codigo = result;
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jydrdboxqxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

Si esta funcionalidad no es suficiente puedes crear un servicio y agregarlo en el provider del componente A y utilizar rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que segun el scope vas a poder manipular tus variables en ese momento, ademas de eso recuerda que si el otro componente lo llamas puedes acceder tanto por *@Input* u *@Output*, pero igual lo podrias manejar por una variable de ser necesario.

Si puedes agrega un poco de codigo para ver como se podria solucionar.